# Given $a \oplus b = a+b+3ab$, prove that $\mathbb{Q \setminus \{-{1 \over 3}\}}$, is an abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Given the question:

> Define the binary operation $\oplus$ as $a \oplus b = a+b+3ab$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q \setminus \{-{1 \over 3}\}}$, is an abelian group.

this is what I have so far:

to prove the group is an abelian group i need to show $a \oplus b = -\frac{1}{3} $iff   $ a=-\frac{1}{3}$ or $ b=-\frac{1}{3} $

and show $(a \oplus b) \oplus c = a \oplus (b\oplus c)$ (associative)

I figured out the first part:
$$ a+b+3ab+ \frac{1}{3} = 0$$

$$ a +3ab = -b -\frac{1}{3}$$

$$3a+9ab = -3b-1$$

$$3a(1+3b) = -3b-1$$

$$\frac{3a(1+3b)}{3(1+3b)} = \frac{-3b-1}{3(1+3b)}$$

$$a = -\frac{1}{3}$$ 
therefore $$ b \neq -\frac{1}{3} $$

the second part is where im stuck, i know its something to do with expanding it all but im very confused with the c part, can someone show me how i can show that its associative?

-thanks

Comment: Do you mean "abelian".  This object would be abelian if $a \oplus b = b \oplus a$ (which you have not shown).  If you don't mean abelian, what is the definition of "abelion"?  Also, the two checks you mention show that this object is a semigroup (operation is closed and associative).  Did you also show that the object has an identity under the operation and that it contains the inverses of all of its elements?  Where is that work?

Comment: You need to show more than that; your first issue shows that the operation is well defined (that is, that the sum of two rationals different from $-\frac{1}{3}$ is a rational different from $-\frac{1}{3}$. Your second part would only show the operation is associative. To show it's an abelian group, you would *also* need to show the existence of a neutral element (a $z$ rational different from $-\frac{1}{3}$ with the property that for every rational $x$ different from $-\frac{1}{3}$, $z\oplus x = x\oplus z = x$; *and* (cont)

Comment: (cont) and that for every rational $x$ different from $-\frac{1}{3}$ there is a rational $y$ different from $-\frac{1}{3}$ such that $x\oplus y = y\oplus x = z$ (the same $z$ from the previous part. This would show it is a group. And finally, that for all rationals $x$ and $y$, both different from $-\frac{1}{3}$, $x\oplus y = y\oplus x$.  

As to your second part: write out the two expressions and compare them. Same for the last one I mention. The other two... you'll have to think about them a bit first.

Comment: Also, your "therefore" is just wrong. What you have is that: in the step before you conclude $a=-\frac{1}{3}$: you can only do the cancellation if $1+3b\neq 0$; that is, if $b\neq -\frac{1}{3}$. If $b=-\frac{1}{3}$, you are done; if $b\neq -\frac{1}{3}$, then you can do the cancellation and conclude that $a=-\frac{1}{3}$. The conclusion is **not** that $b\neq -\frac{1}{3}$, but rather that if $a\oplus b=-\frac{1}{3}$, then either $b=-\frac{1}{3}$ or $a=-\frac{1}{3}$, which is what you actually want to show.

Comment: This is the multiplication on $\mathbb Q^*$ in disguise since $$3(a\oplus b)+1=(3a+1)\cdot(3b+1)$$ The abelian group property follows by the morphism $a\mapsto3a+1$.

Comment: thankyou all for your help, i am able to make sense of this question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q:=\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{-1/3\}$.

Clearly, this $\oplus$ is well defined in $Q$: $a\oplus b$ is always rational number since we deal only with elementary operation in $\mathbb{Q}$ which are closed in $\mathbb{Q}$. We must only check if the result can be $-1/3$.
In that case we get $$a+b+3ab =-{1\over 3}$$ so we have
$$1+3a+3b+9ab = 0 \Longrightarrow (1+3a)(1+3b)=0$$
which can not be since $a,b\in Q$ and thus $\oplus $ is closed in $Q$.

**Associativity:**

$$(a \oplus b) \oplus c = (a+b+3ab)\oplus c = a+b+3ab + c+ 3c(a+b+3ab) = a+b+c+3(ab+bc+ac)+9abc$$

and the same we got for

$$a \oplus (b\oplus c)= ....=a+b+c+3(ab+bc+ac)+9abc$$

**Commutative:**

$$a\oplus b = a+b+3ab = b+a++3ba =b\oplus a$$

**Neutral element:**

$$a\oplus e = a,\;\;\;\;\; \forall a \in Q$$

Then we have $$e+3ae =0,\;\;\;\;\; \forall a \in Q$$

Since $a\ne -1/3$ we must have $e=0$. So $0$ is nevtral element in $Q$.

**Inverse:**

Let $a'$ be inverse for $a\ne -1/3$, then $a\oplus a'=0$:

$$ a+a' +3aa' =0$$

Then $$a' = -{a\over 3a+1}$$
which is always well defined.

So $(Q,\oplus)$ is commutative group.